# MPMoviePlayer won't play using Swift

Tags: swift, ios8, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I have an MPMoviePlayer that won't play. I don't know what's wrong with my code. I'm positive that my fileUrl is there. Thanks for the responses in advance!

```
    moviePlayer =  MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: fileUrl)
    moviePlayer.prepareToPlay()
    self.view.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)
    moviePlayer.setFullscreen(true, animated: true)
    moviePlayer.play()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope your fileUrl is correct try this,

Declare moviePlayer outside func viewDidLoad()

```
var moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController()
```

To test put this code in func viewDidLoad()

```
        moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL:fileUrl)
        moviePlayer.view.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        self.view.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)
        moviePlayer.setFullscreen(true, animated: true)
        moviePlayer.prepareToPlay()
        moviePlayer.play()
        moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Embedded
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried this, but unfortunately it did not work. I added an if statement and a println as well to check if fileUrl is nil, and every time the correct fileUrl printed out. The moviePlayer still does not play however.

Comment: I tried creating another view with a button on it that loads the moviePlayer with the fileUrl, and that worked. I think the issue with this code is with the self.view.addSubview(moviePlayer.view) line...self right now is a nib overlay

Comment: strange I tried with the above code in my app with my video file in bundle and was successfully able to play..

Comment: I think I may have figured it out...I believe I was adding it to the wrong view. Instead, I add it on top of my imagepickercontroller like so camera.view.addSubview(moviePlayer.view) and the mpmovieplayer appears....Silly me, thanks for your help!